# OpenCV pixel manipulation sometimes is not working

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I try to modify a BGRA mat using a pointer like this:

```
//Bound the value between 0 to 255
uchar boundPixelValue(double c) {
    c = int(c);
    if (c > 255)
        c = 255;
    if (c < 0)
        c = 0;
    return (uchar) c;
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                //This loop is accessing the first three channels
                mat.ptr<Vec4b>(i)[j][k] = boundPixelValue(
                        1.0 * mat.ptr<Vec4b>(i)[j][k] * max / avg[k]);
            }
```

But this gives different outputs every time, sometimes work and sometimes give a white blank image. I am suspecting if this is due to the noncontinuous data, can anyone help?

One extra question, usually we access the columns of a 2D array first before accessing the rows because it is usually faster. However, I have to access the pixel using `mat.ptr<Vec4b>(row)[col]`. So, should I loop through the rows first then column?

Comment: What are `boundPixelValue`, `max`, `avg`? What types?

Comment: I added the boundPixelValue in the question. "max" is integer type, "avg" is an integer array.

Comment: Check the code in my answer. I'll explain better what it does if it works for you (I haven't enough details to guarantee that it works now, please see how to do a [mcve]).

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it could be rewritten as a simple matrix expression on the `split` channels (that you'd then `merge` back together). `boundPixelValue` looks like regular saturation which OpenCV will do.

Comment: Did you try mat.at<Vec4b>(i,j)[k] ? Also try flood image with known values and check if result correct.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for your suggestion, you reminded me to use split and merge :-P I splited the mat to 4 mats and manipulate the first 3 channels, the problem seems not to occur anymore although I don't know why. But since I have to multiply a double type value to the pixel `ptr[col]*doubleValue`, I can't use the overloaded operator `*=` to mulitply a scalar directly, I have to use saturate_cast to cast the result to uchar first and put back to the pixel. Any better solutions?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Since I am more concern about the speed, I try to avoid using `at`, and I want to use pointer instead. But thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Easier, less intensive way of doing is:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> matArray;
cv::split(toBoundMat, matArray);

matArray[0].setTo(0, matArray[0] < 0);
matArray[0].setTo(255, matArray[0] > 255);

matArray[1].setTo(0, matArray[1] < 0);
matArray[1].setTo(255, matArray[1] > 255);

matArray[2].setTo(0, matArray[2] < 0);
matArray[2].setTo(255, matArray[2] > 255);

cv::Mat boundedMat;

cv::merge(matArray, boundedMat);
```

But I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Your double data may have values between 1.7E +/- 308. You either are expecting a very specific kind of data, or you are going to mess it up. If you want to make a Mat visualizable, just normalize it like this:

```
cv::normalize(inMat, destMat, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX);

cv::cvtColor(destMat, destMat, CV_8UC1) //--(8 bit visualizable mat)
```

This will check the min and max of your current Mat and will set the minimum to 0, the maximum to 255, and all the in between values proportionally :)